# Insert line in named range without modifying it

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google doc spreadsheet with some columns that are named range

```
NAMED_RANGE_1
_data_!B3:B1000
```

Where B1 and B2 are the header of the page (they are frozen). I'm inserting lines in this table in a manner to keep the most recent entries at the top. So I right-click on the B3 row and do insert one above. So my most recent entry is on top. But, my named range is now this:

```
NAMED_RANGE_1
_data_!B4:B1000
```

Is their a way to insert directly into the named range's range without modifying it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer is just no, named ranges in google spreadsheets don't let you do absolute referencing, i.e. putting $ in front of cell references like $B$3:$B:$1000.  Seems like that would work right?  But if you put that in, it just boots the $ symbols and treats it as a relative reference.

A script possibility, put in a third frozen row, so your named range is B4:B1000.  Whenever cell B3 is edited, it cuts and pastes all values everything down one row.  That way your named range stays the same.